# Are the images produced from the "Export mosaic dataset items" orthorectified?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, mosaic-dataset, orthorectification

I am trying to find whether or not the orthorectification is done to these images like it is for the export data, I can't find anything about this.